# Convert a string array to collection of string in c#

Tags: c#

I'm facing a problem in my code, where I have properties of two different models whose type cannot be changed by me. One is a string array and one is a collection of string. Now I need to add all the elements in the string array to the collection. I'm providing a sample code below.

```
Collection<string> collection = new Collection<string>();
string[] arraystring = new string[]{"Now","Today","Tomorrow"};
collection.Add(/*Here I need to give the elements of the above array*/);
```

Note: I cannot change the Collection to ICollection. It has to be Collection only.

Comment: What problem? and why that note?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Collection` is already created you can enumerate the items of the array and call `Add`

```
Collection<string> collection = new Collection<string>();
string[] arraystring = new string[]{"Now","Today","Tomorrow"};
foreach(var s in arrayString)
    collection.Add(s);
```

Otherwise you can initialize a `Collection` from an array of strings

```
string[] arraystring = new string[]{"Now","Today","Tomorrow"};
Collection<string> collection = new Collection<string>(arraystring);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the correct ctor, passing in the array:

```
Collection<string> collection = new Collection<string>(arraystring);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give your string array by parameter to `Collection<string>` ctor, like here:

```
var collection = new Collection<string>(new[] { "Now", "Today", "Tomorrow" });
```

About `Collection<T>` you can read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

For a clean solution, you could use the ForEach static method of Array like so:

```
Collection<string> collection = new Collection<string>();
string[] arraystring = new string[] { "Now", "Today", "Tomorrow" };
Array.ForEach(arraystring, str => collection.Add(str));
```